# Create a dataframe of top 10 recommendatons for each content

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I am following a content base recommender system from here https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-from-scratch-a-content-based-movie-recommender-with-natural-language-processing-25ad400eb243 .

After calculating the cosine similarity matrix, a function is created to recommend the top 10 similar content to the content we put in.

```
# creating a Series for the movie titles so they are associated to an ordered numerical
# list I will use in the function to match the indexes

indices = pd.Series(df.index)

#  defining the function that takes in movie title 
# as input and returns the top 10 recommended movies

def recommendations(title, cosine_sim = cosine_sim):

    # initializing the empty list of recommended movies
    recommended_movies = []

    # gettin the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[indices == title].index[0]

    # creating a Series with the similarity scores in descending order
    score_series = pd.Series(cosine_sim[idx]).sort_values(ascending = False)

    # getting the indexes of the 10 most similar movies
    top_10_indexes = list(score_series.iloc[1:11].index)

    # populating the list with the titles of the best 10 matching movies
    for i in top_10_indexes:
        recommended_movies.append(list(df.index)[i])

    return recommended_movies
```

The above gives me the top 10 contents for each content I enter.  I would like to create a dataframe where column 1 would be all the contents, and columns 2-10, would be the top similar movies.  So each row would be the original content and the top 10 similar movies excluding itself.  I am new to python and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving the input title and its recommendations in a data frame and then run `pivot_table` as needed with ranks for values. However, first adjust function to return a dictionary and run it with a list comprehension passing result into the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
indices = pd.Series(df.index)

def recommendations(title, cosine_sim = cosine_sim):    
    ...

    df_dict = {'title' = [title] * 10, 
               'recommended' = recommended_movies,
               'rank' = list(range(1, 11))}

    return  df_dict


# BUILD DATA FRAME FROM LIST OF DICTS
df = pd.DataFrame([recommendations(t) for t in indices.to_list()])

# PIVOT FOR TITLE X OTHERS VIEW 
pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'title',  columns = 'recommended',
               values = 'rank', aggunc = 'max')
```